# How to use JmsTemplate with HTTP proxy

Tags: java, spring-jms

I am using a Spring `JmsTemplate` to publish messages to an Azure Service Bus topic. When running on my company's network I need `JmsTemplate` to use an HTTP proxy similar to what you can do with a `RestTemplate` or `WebClient`. I can't find any good examples on how to do that. Is it possible, and if so could you provide me with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one pattern for configuring `JmsTemplate` with an HTTP proxy. If anyone has a better pattern please post it here.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements ApplicationRunner {
    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jms;
    @Autowired
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    final String topicName = "myTopic";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        Supplier<ProxyHandler> supplier = () -> new HttpProxyHandler(new InetSocketAddress("my.proxy.com", 83));

        ((JmsConnectionFactory) connectionFactory).setExtension(JmsConnectionExtensions.PROXY_HANDLER_SUPPLIER.toString(), (conn, remote) -> supplier);
        jms.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        jms.convertAndSend(topicName, "Hello World");
        System.out.println("Published \"Hello World\"");
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = topicName, containerFactory = "topicJmsListenerContainerFactory", subscription = "mySub")
    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received " + message);
    }
}
```